# How to find the number of rearranged elements in array

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, linq

I have a List as follows:

```
{1, 7, 4, 9, 5}
```

And I need a **sorted** List as `{1, 4, 5, 7, 9}`

I want to find the number of elements swapped to get this sorted list.

After 1st Move: `{1, 4, 7, 9, 5}`

After 2nd Move: `{1, 4, 5, 7, 9}`

Answer here would be: **2** *Moves*

Which is the optimum way to do it?
Using *Linq* is there a way?

Comment: What is your definition of "rearranged"?

Comment: If you are trying to find out what numbers are already in the 'correct' order, you could loop through the array and check

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? Why do you need to know "how many numbers"? If you just want a sorted list, you can just do array.Sort()

Comment: You could mean "are these elements in the same position they would be in in a sorted version of the list" or you could mean "is each element larger than the preceding element and smaller than the succeeding element". If you're trying to find the elements that don't match those criteria, they can have two different answers. I'm also ignoring (but you may not be able to) equal elements.

Comment: @trailmax How many numbers are moved to get the sorted list.

Comment: `{1, 3, 4, 5, 2}`  - do we have to move *one* number (just move `2` into position 2) or do we have to move *four* numbers?

Comment: @NishanthSuraj the expected result here is : 7 and 9 ?

Comment: Did you meant consecutive sorted numbers ? and if so, what you're looking for, the amount of the longest or it's values ? i'm asking because there can be couple of consecutive sorted items. e.g {1, 7}, {4, 9} and in a non-consecutive: {1, 7}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 4, 5}. So a need of clarification is needed.

Comment: There's a few ways to do this, but please update your post to include what you actually have tried and what isn't working so we can help you.

Comment: Use bubbleSort and count the times you sort

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I've *understood you right* you want to count *deletions / insertions*:

1. Take `7` and put it on 4th place,
2. Take `9` and put it on 5th place,
3. Take `5` and put it on 3d place

we have `{1, 4, 5, 7, 9}` which is *sorted* with `3` operations. If' it's your case you can

Sort the list:

```
 {1, 7, 4, 9, 5}  # initial
  |  |  |  |  |
 {1, 4, 5, 7, 9}  # sorted
```

now build the *unordered graph*:

- **nodes**: numbers (`1`, `7`, ..., `5`)
- **edges**: between numbers in each column (initial and sorted list): `1 - 1`, `7 - 4`, `4 - 5`, `9 - 7`, `5 - 9`

find out all the loops:

```
1 - 1          # length == 1
7 - 4 - 5 - 9  # length == 4
```

Sum all the `length - 1` of all loops:

```
(1 - 1) + (4 - 1) = 3
```

**Edit:** In case of *insertions* (please, note that we don't *swap* items) only the answer is

```
|List| - |Longest_Non_Descreasing_Sequence(List)|
```

were `|...|` stands for *number of items* (`Count`, `Length`, `Size` etc). In your case:

```
|{1, 7, 4, 9, 5}| = 5
|Longest_Non_Descreasing_Sequence({1, 7, 4, 9, 5})| = |{1, 4, 5}| = 3

 result = 5 - 3 = 2
```

Algorithm:

1. Find out the Longest Non Descreasing Sequence (LNDS), say, with a help of *dynamic programming*
2. Insert the rest items into it.

In your case for `{1, 7, 4, 9, 5}` we have `{1, 4, 5}` for LNDS and two items `{7, 9}` to insert:

```
 {1, 7, 4, 9, 5} # initial List {1, 4, 5} is LNDS
 {1, 4, 9, 5, 7} # 7 inserted into {1, 4, 5} we have {1, 4, 5, 7} as LNDS
 {1, 4, 5, 7, 9} # 9 inserted into {1, 4, 5, 7}
```